# C# HttpWebRequest not failing SSL certificate but edge browser is failing request

Tags: c#, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am trying to do a GET for a url like https://somedomain.subdomain.com,
when i try the URL in Edge and chrome browser it is not showing SSL padlock and shows "your connection to the site is not secured. This Site does not have a certificate".

But when i do get for same URL in C# .NET 6.0 code it doesn't show any SSL error. Below is sample code.

Question:
How to do know why Edge browser is failing ssl and how to have same behavior in C# code.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://somedomain.subdomain.com");
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;            
            request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
            
            
private static bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
// here sslPolicyErrors  is coming as None and there is no error/exception in SSL cert validation.
}
```

Comment: Does the website have a valid certificate? If possible, could you please provide the url link so that we can have a check? Besides, please also try in other browsers like Firefox to check if it has the same issue.

Comment: thanks for reply. Firefox is showing it as valid SSL (padlock symbol). Is there any option to check logs/details why Edge is saying site does not have certificate.  In C# code also the ServerCertificateValidationCallback is getting certificate object.. Only Edge is showing invalid certificate.

Comment: I think that's because Firefox uses a different set of certs which might cause the different results. As Edge and Chrome are both based on chromium, so they have the same behavior. Does it work in Edge InPrivate mode? For deeper investigating, you can open F12 devtools in Edge/Chrome and click **Security** tab to check detailed error information.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, it shows same message in edge private mode. also tried with devtolls and security tab doesn't show any additional details. it just says "this is an error page".

Comment: After research, I think we can't get the same validation mechanism in Edge and C# codes, because Edge has other mechanism like SmartScreen. If you just want to have the same result in Edge and codes, I'm afraid we can't. If you want to check the detailed certificate error message, I think it will show on page after clicking **Advanced** like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHaad.png. Or if you have any other demands, please share it here.

Comment: Can you pls share more details on how to go to "Advanced". In my case site also needs Authentication, so I am also getting 403 in addition to edge/chrome not showing padlock icon for SSL

Comment: I just go to a sample site and it will show error if the page is not secure. There's an "Advanced" button on the page, after I click the button, it will show detailed error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjVBA.png. It could be better that you can provide a screenshot of the issue or a video which shows the reproducing steps of the issue.